# word usage "to treat" differently

Tags: word-usage

Which of sentences is correct ?

We still  **xxxxx** it a miracle that they were able to do so.

**xxxxx**  take, think, consider, find

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first thing to note is that if you were writing the sentence using "treat" it would need to be:

> "We still treat it **as** a miracle that they were able to do so."

Of your suggested alternatives "take" is the only one that also requires that sentence construction.

> "We still take it **as** a miracle that they were able to do so."

For you original sentence construction

> "We still think it a miracle that they were able to do so."

or

> "We still consider it a miracle that they were able to do so."

or

> "We still find it a miracle that they were able to do so."

are all work grammatically, however "find" does not sound right for some reason.

My personal choice would be for the more formal sounding "consider", although "think" is an acceptable alternative.

Comment: I think your instincts are correct but not stated strongly enough.  "consider it a miracle" is natural and any native speaker might say it.  while "think it a miracle" is technically correct it undeniably sounds odd and few native speakers would ever say this, unless it was specifically for a stilted, formal effect.  the same is true for all the other alternatives except "treat it as miracle," which sounds natural enough to me.